# how do I add a percentage increase to all product prices in Magento 1.4?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I need to increase the prices of all products in the store by 3% and have come across this nice and simple script for adding a fixed price to all products:

```
 $priceToAdd = 6;

 $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
 $write->query("
 UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal val
 SET  val.value = (val.value + $priceToAdd)
 WHERE  val.attribute_id = (
 SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute eav
 WHERE eav.entity_type_id = 4
   AND eav.attribute_code = 'price'
 )
");
```

Does anybody know how i would alter this code to add a fixed percentage to all products ?

This is the new code that I'm trying ?

```
<?php require 'app/Mage.php'; Mage::app();

 $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
 ;
 foreach ($products as $product) {
 $roundup = $product->setPrice($product->getPrice()* 1.03);
 echo ceil($roundup);
 $product->save();
 }

 ?>
```

This code works fine but now looking to round up the number ?
Many thanks

Comment: change `attribute_Id = (` to `attribute_ID in (`

Comment: @xQbert sorry for delay in my comment , been off line, not sure waht you mean ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
     ;
 foreach ($products as $product) {
     $product->setPrice($product->getPrice() * 1.03);
     $product->save();
 }
```

Comment: I just wrote it _right now_. In general, you should never be doing direct SQL requests in a Magento app. You should always use the Magento API because of its ORM. To learn more about Magento ORM look at http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm

Comment: what i meant was is this an alternative script to the one one in my post ? thanks

Comment: Yes, its better because it uses the Magento API and increases prices by 3% instead of a fixed amount.

Comment: if its in your magento root directory you have to add at the top:
`<?php
 require 'app/Mage.php'; Mage::app();`

Comment: sorry for delay in my comment , been off line, thanks for the help

Comment: works fine , would you know how to get this to round to the nearest .10 so 176.00 would round to 183.30 instead of 183.34 ? many thanks

Comment: can't get the syntax to work I'm trying ceil to round up the number , but don't know the code to add ?? thanks